# Scrapy items outputed as tuples instead of list

Tags: scrapy

For whatever reason all items are returned as tuples. Not sure what I am missing. In all other spiders and projects it was just a list (when i use extract()).

```
{'acne': (None,),
'function': ([u'\u2027Preservative'],),
'function0': u'\u2027Preservative',
'irritant': (None,),
'name': (u'Potassium Sorbate',),
'safety': (u'3',),
'url': 'http://cosdna.com/eng/383bb7435.html'}
```

Here is my spider code.

```
def parse(self, response):
    inspect_response(response, self)
    a = response.xpath('//table//tr')

    for i in a:
        item = CosdnaExtItem()
        item['name'] = i.xpath('./td/a/text()').extract_first(),
        item['url'] = i.xpath('./td/a/@href').extract_first(),
        item['function'] = i.xpath('.//td[2]/span//text()').extract(),
        item['acne'] = i.xpath('.//td[3]/span//text()').extract_first(),
        item['irritant'] = i.xpath('.//td[4]/span//text()').extract_first(),
        item['safety'] =  i.xpath('.//td[5]/div//text()').extract_first(),

        yield item
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note extra commas at the end of lines:

```
item['function'] = i.xpath('.//td[2]/span//text()').extract(),
```

in Python

```
x = y,
```

is the same as

```
x = (y,)
```